# recyclerview checkbox checked/unchecked automatically when i am scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

//this is my QuestionHolder

```
private class QuestionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private JSONObject question;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private TextView question_txt;
    public QuestionHolder(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_item, parent, false));

        checkBox  = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_checkbox);

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //try {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ID: " + question.get("_id"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //} catch (JSONException e) { }
                // TODO: If this was checked then add the question's id to the answered list
            }
        });
        question_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

// here i am binding the questiontxt

```
    public void bind(JSONObject question) {
        this.question = question;
        try {
            question_txt.setText(question.getString("_question"));
        } catch (JSONException je) { }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO: If this was checked then add the question's id to the answered list
    }
}
```

// this is my Adapter which extend QuestionHOlder

```
private class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionHolder> {

    private JSONArray questions;

    public QuestionAdapter(JSONArray questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    @Override
    public QuestionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new QuestionHolder(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), parent);
    }
```

//this is onBindViewHolder

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(QuestionHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            final JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(position);
            holder.bind(question);
        } catch (JSONException je) { }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return questions.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: recyclerview checkbox checked/unchecked automatically

Comment: Thats what you want to happen?

Comment: No I want it be checked when i click on checkbox not automatically when i scroll down